# GKE clusters point to unavailable apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, contour

**How to reproduce the issue:**

Spin up a new GKE cluster (using UI or CLI) and once the cluster is ready list all available apiservices. See output below, as you can see v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io is marked as not available due to missing endpoints.

This frequently messed up the automated setup of our infrastructure, as as part of the setup contour ingress failed during its installation. You can find more information in the K8S Slack / Contour / GKE Channel: https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/C09R1TL6A/p1600084503124400

```
kubectl get apiservices
NAME                                   SERVICE                      AVAILABLE                  AGE
v1.                                    Local                        True                       75s
v1.admissionregistration.k8s.io        Local                        True                       75s
v1.apiextensions.k8s.io                Local                        True                       75s
v1.apps                                Local                        True                       75s
v1.authentication.k8s.io               Local                        True                       75s
v1.authorization.k8s.io                Local                        True                       75s
v1.autoscaling                         Local                        True                       75s
v1.batch                               Local                        True                       75s
v1.cloud.google.com                    Local                        True                       9s
v1.coordination.k8s.io                 Local                        True                       75s
v1.networking.k8s.io                   Local                        True                       75s
v1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io           Local                        True                       75s
v1.scheduling.k8s.io                   Local                        True                       75s
v1.storage.k8s.io                      Local                        True                       75s
v1alpha1.migration.k8s.io              Local                        True                       34s
v1alpha1.nodemanagement.gke.io         Local                        True                       33s
v1beta1.admissionregistration.k8s.io   Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.apiextensions.k8s.io           Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.authentication.k8s.io          Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.authorization.k8s.io           Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.batch                          Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.certificates.k8s.io            Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.cloud.google.com               Local                        True                       9s
v1beta1.coordination.k8s.io            Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.discovery.k8s.io               Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.extensions                     Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server   False (MissingEndpoints)   39s
v1beta1.networking.gke.io              Local                        True                       36s
v1beta1.networking.k8s.io              Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.node.k8s.io                    Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.policy                         Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io      Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.scheduling.k8s.io              Local                        True                       75s
v1beta1.snapshot.storage.k8s.io        Local                        True                       35s
v1beta1.storage.k8s.io                 Local                        True                       75s
v1beta2.networking.gke.io              Local                        True                       36s
v2beta1.autoscaling                    Local                        True                       75s
v2beta2.autoscaling                    Local                        True                       75s
```

Isnt this a bug on the GKE side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can report issues with Google products by following below link:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Support: Docs: Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)*

You will need to choose the: `Create new Google Kubernetes Engine issue` under `Compute` section.

---

I can confirm that I stumbled upon the same issue when creating **new** `GKE` cluster:

```sh
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server   False (FailedDiscoveryCheck)   54s
```

I tested this behavior on the following `GKE` versions:

- Static version:

  - `1.15.12-gke.2`
- Release channels:

  - Regular channel - `1.16.13-gke.1`
  - Rapid channel - `1.17.9-gke.1504`

Steps:

- Create a `GKE` cluster
- Run `$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER-NAME --zone=ZONE-NAME`
- Run `$ kubectl get apiservices` when UI showed `Ready` status

Cluster status was `Ready` in:

- `Cloud Console`
- `$ gcloud container clusters list`

This issue persisted from `30` to `90` seconds depending on the cluster version used.

Example:

- `$ kubectl get apiservices`

```sh
NAME                                   SERVICE                      AVAILABLE                      AGE
v1.                                    Local                        True                           99s
v1.admissionregistration.k8s.io        Local                        True                           99s
v1.apiextensions.k8s.io                Local                        True                           99s
v1.apps                                Local                        True                           99s
v1.authentication.k8s.io               Local                        True                           99s
v1.authorization.k8s.io                Local                        True                           99s
v1.autoscaling                         Local                        True                           98s
v1.batch                               Local                        True                           98s
v1.cloud.google.com                    Local                        True                           12s
v1.coordination.k8s.io                 Local                        True                           98s
v1.networking.k8s.io                   Local                        True                           98s
v1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io           Local                        True                           98s
v1.scheduling.k8s.io                   Local                        True                           98s
v1.storage.k8s.io                      Local                        True                           98s
v1alpha1.migration.k8s.io              Local                        True                           50s
v1alpha1.nodemanagement.gke.io         Local                        True                           49s
v1alpha1.scalingpolicy.kope.io         Local                        True                           51s
v1beta1.admissionregistration.k8s.io   Local                        True                           99s
v1beta1.apiextensions.k8s.io           Local                        True                           99s
v1beta1.authentication.k8s.io          Local                        True                           99s
v1beta1.authorization.k8s.io           Local                        True                           99s
v1beta1.batch                          Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.certificates.k8s.io            Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.cloud.google.com               Local                        True                           12s
v1beta1.coordination.k8s.io            Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.extensions                     Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server   False (FailedDiscoveryCheck)   54s
v1beta1.networking.gke.io              Local                        True                           50s
v1beta1.networking.k8s.io              Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.node.k8s.io                    Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.policy                         Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io      Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.scheduling.k8s.io              Local                        True                           98s
v1beta1.storage.k8s.io                 Local                        True                           98s
v1beta2.networking.gke.io              Local                        True                           50s
v2beta1.autoscaling                    Local                        True                           98s
v2beta2.autoscaling                    Local                        True                           98s
```